# Error 'compile swift source files (arm64)' when building project with Xcode 13

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire, sdwebimage, xcode13

I am developing an app with Xcode 13.0 (13A233) on Macbook with an M1 chip. After updating pods to the latest version, the pods are complaining about error

> CompileSwiftSources normal arm64 com.apple.xcode.tools.swift.compiler (in target 'Alamofire' from project 'Pods')

and not building for either real devices or simulators.

I'm including the following pods in the project:

- Alamofire
- IQKeyboardManager
- NVActivityIndicatorView
- FillableLoaders
- SQlite.Swift
- SDWebImage
- SwiftDataTables

I've already applied the following solutions for the main project and all pods projects:

- Upon updating pods, clean build folder (using Shift + Command + K)
- Excluding arm64 architecture for 'Any iOS Simulator SDK' from Excluded architectures
- Set 'YES' to 'Build Active Architecture Only'
- There is no field called 'VALID_ARCHS' in the User-Defined section
- [Solution provided over Medium](https://milanpanchal24.medium.com/xcode-12-building-for-ios-simulator-but-linking-in-object-file-built-for-ios-file-for-8c0cc28ec832)

You can see [Error details](https://ibb.co/s9gTvhb) on this screenshot.

### Note

I know that there are many answers related to these questions, but I've tried each of them, and when I am not able to resolve it with those, I am posting question here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, I was able to figure out the issue, and it was related to the version of the pod that was being used in code.

So, If you're still experiencing the same, I recommend to:

- Check the compatibility of the pod which is causing issue
- Uninstall and install pods again

Answer (score 2):

Personally solved it by doing all you mentioned and also switching to new build system. Xcode => File => Workspace settings...

There change the build system to "New Build System".

[image: Workspace settings screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

Remaining solution

1.Remove any architecture related run script from your project of Project target

2.Uninstall and install pods

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I did to make it work.

1. Delete derived data.
2. Quit Xcode.
3. Re-Open Xcode
4. Clean Build
5. Build